# sys.path.append doesn't work with Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have Blender 2.66a which is an application that offers Python 3.3 APIs, On my system I have an installation of Python 3.2 with several modules that I wish to use inside Blender, I tried both

```
sys.path.append(r"/usr/lib/python3.2/")
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python3.2/")
```

and this commands gives no errors, infact even the autocomplete feature works and new modules are indexed, so i tried

```
import tkinter
```

but this generates the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python-tk package')
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python-tk package
```

and I don't get the point of this error because it fails to load a module that it's there asking me to install the same module because that module is not installed ( ? ).

What can cause this obscure problem ?

---

EDIT

**the tkinter module works from the gnome-terminal**

Comment: This has nothing to do with `sys.path.append` not working. You are missing a library the C parts of tkinter need to work.

Comment: @Wooble what library? tkinter works from the regular console, also other modules can be imported without errors from that path

Comment: Did you check the version of python in the console and in the Blender modules? They are probably different, and the `python-tk` package is probably installed only for a specific version.

Comment: @Bakuriu as stated in the post, 3.2 for the python os installation ( where tkinter comes from ) and 3.3 for Blender APIs ( where I'm trying to retrieve tkinter as module ); I'm not sure if this is a real problem by the way, it's always python 3.x

Comment: Did you try to add `/usr/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload` to the path? that's where the `_tkinter` modules lives on linux(at least my machine). Anyway, as explained by delnan I don't think it will work.

Comment: It should maybe be emphasized that `tkinter` and `_tkinter` are *not* the same module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you right, you're using Python 3.3 from Blender but try to include the 3.2 standard library. This is bound to give you a flurry of issues, you should *not* do that. Find another way. It's likely that Blender offers a way to use the 3.3 standard library (and that's 99% compatible with 3.2). Pure-Python third party library can, of course, be included by fiddling with `sys.path`.

The specific issue you're seeing now is likely caused by the version difference. As people have pointed out in the comments, Python 3.3 doesn't find the `_tkinter` extension module. Although it is present (as it works from Python 3.2), it is most likely in a .so file with an [ABI tag](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/) that is incompatible with Blender's Python 3.3, hence it won't even look at it (much like a `module.txt` is not considered for `import module`). **This is a good thing.** Extension modules are highly version-specific, slight ABI mismatches (such as between 3.2 and 3.3, or two 3.3 compiled with different options) can cause pretty much any kind of error, from crashes to memory leaks to silent data corruption or even something completely different.

You can verify whether this is the case via `import _tkinter; print(_tkinter.__file__)` in the 3.2 shell. Alternatively, `_tkinter` may live in a different directory entirely. Adding that directory won't actually fix the real issue outlined above.

Comment: apparently `_tkinter` lives under `/usr/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload/` but appending this path to the `sys.path` doesn't solve anything, I think that this 2 Python version are not compatible in the end.